# I'm currently on Ubuntu version 14.04. How can I update not to the newest version but to 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, updates, downloads

I know 17.10 is the latest. I'm on 14.04. I want to go to 16.04 not 17.10. All tutorials I see online tell how to update to newest version. 
Update 1: That answer is about servers. I'm talking about Ubuntu versions. That answer clearly tells u to make sure ur on the latest versionof ubuntu, whih I am not.

Comment: You actually CANNOT upgrade to 17.10 even if you want to. Stepping through 16.04 is literally a mandatory thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions, is mentioned by @WinEunuuchs2Unix through the link. Through this method, I believe that  most of the additional softwares that you have currently installed in you 14.04 version along with the user data can be retained safely, even after the upgrade.

The other way would be, having a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16. To do so,

1. Visit [Ubuntu Downloads Page](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)
2. Download Ubuntu 16 ISO file.
3. Use the Startup Disk Creator application in Ubuntu to prepare a Live/Bootable USB. Follow this : [Create a bootable USB in Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0) , to complete this step.
4. Once you have the Live USB, then you're good to go. Just boot your machine using the Live USB and follow the onscreen instructions.

NOTE : Just a piece of advice. Keep the installation directory same. As in, the directory which stored your Ubuntu 14 can be used for Ubuntu 16 too. This way, though you might loose a few of your previously installed applications, but still you will have the user data OR the contents of the 'Home' directory.

Enjoy Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

### Backup

It is risky to install an operating system. It is even more risky to upgrade an operating system to the next released version.

So backup at least all the data that you cannot afford to lose to another drive, and disconnect that drive before starting to install or upgrade your system. If you can, it is a good idea to backup the whole system, for example make a compressed image with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org).

### Upgrading to 16.04 LTS

I had problems upgrading to 16.04 LTS. Luckily **I backed up my previous version** before starting the adventure.

It is more likely that you succeed, if you

- remove all specially installed programs (for example via PPAs, and then remove the PPAs),
- make the original system fully up to date,
- and then start the upgrading process with `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

  Check that it 'wants to' upgrade to the next LTS release, which is 16.04 LTS in your case.

### Fresh installation

You are much more likely to succeed with a fresh installation. In this case you can

- use a cloning tool to create a USB boot drive. The Startup Disk Creator in 14.04 LTS is buggy, so use another tool, for example **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb).
- make a completely fresh installation, and afterwards copy your personal files from the backup to where you want them in the new Ubuntu system,
- keep the `/home` directory by making it a separate **home** partition. During the [fresh] installation, select 'Something else' at the partitioning window, and specify both a root partition (/) and a home partition (/home) as well as a swap partition.

  This is likely to work, and in that case you will keep the personal files stored in the `/home` directory tree and also the settings and tweaks that are stored there (often in hidden configurations files and directories).